# Why do I have a single vertex connected to 2 edge loops?

Tags: modeling, uv, topology

In a UV Mesh I have a single Vertex connected to '2 Edge Loops'

One on the top of a cylinder, and one on the bottom.

I have to remove either the top or the bottom Edge Loop, Then I delete half of the other Edge Loop.

I can not determine where this lone Vertex is located, because "it moves"

[Video demonstrating the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHTaj4GuOSo)

[image]

Comment: I had to deal with this once, it's hard to find that vertex and maybe even impossible because your selection mode is set to edge, you should also check no double vertices are present

Comment: I do that a lot in Blender and it always says "0 Vertices have been removed" even though there is are 2 vertices in the same spot.

Comment: Could you post your blend file so we can look at it? I might have a solution for it but I am not sure I understand the problem entirely

Comment: Of course. How do you do that exactly?

Comment: Use this to upload your file and then update your answer above with the generated link http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a single vertex, non of your top and bottom of the barrel faces have UV coordinates.

If you move that "one single vertex" in the UV Image editor you will find that there are actually several overlapping vertex in the 0,0 coordinate, in fact if you move more of them you will start seeing faces appear which correspond to the bottom and top of your barrel.

In other words you have to unwrap the rest of the mesh also

Comment: Alright, thank you for your time, and have a nice day.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Is this the solution? If so please consider marking the answer as correct, or at upvoting if it helped you